# Catch process which exits immediately and respawns fast

Tags: process, kill

On Linux server there are many log messages like these:

```
Jul 17 09:22:34 sweden sudo[3631848]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [myuser]
Jul 17 09:22:34 sweden sudo[3631848]: pam_sss(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=30044 euid=0 tty= ruser=myuser rhost= user=myuser
Jul 17 09:22:34 sweden sudo[3631848]: pam_sss(sudo:auth): received for user myuser: 7 (Authentication failure)
Jul 17 09:22:35 sweden sudo[3631849]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Jul 17 09:22:35 sweden sudo[3631849]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
```

They are produced by an unknown program which just floods the journal. Every ~500ms a new process is spawned, but I cannot identify the origin (neither command, nor its parent).

How can I stop (`SIGSTOP`) such a process, which lives for extremely short time and always changes its PID?

I have tried to see it with `watch -n0.1 'ps fuxww'`, but nothing appears there.

Comment: This was happening, because something left after failed Ansible task spawning an elusive process. I had have to reboot the machine and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look for processes running as `myuser` and investigate what they do.
2. Run `crontab -u myuser -l` to see if they have any cron jobs that run `sudo` (either directly in the crontab entry or in a script run from cron)
3. `grep myuser /etc/crontab /etc/cron*/*` in case there are any system cron jobs for `myuser`.
4. run `atq` to see if they have any `at` jobs queued.
5. Also look in `~myuser/.config/systemd/user/` to see if they have any systemd timer jobs scheduled.
6. run `grep -r pam_securetty /etc/pam.d/` to find out which pam services are configured to use securetty when you don't even have an `/etc/securetty` file(*).  `sudo` will be one of them because that's what's generate the auth log messages, perhaps others, perhaps one of the `/etc/pam.d/common-*` files.

(*) `/etc/securetty` is used to limit which ttys root is allowed to login on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is nice summary for searching scheduled tasks. I didn't find there any scheduled tasks though, because my problem was caused by interrupted or failed Ansible task, which was spawning a process on its own.

Comment: I would include `systemctl list-timers` and `systemctl --user list-timers` in this list as well. Systemd collects even user units from different "system" directories, like: `/etc/systemd/user`, `/usr/local/lib/systemd/user` etc. (see `man 5 systemd.unit`)